# Riemann-Roch Theorem over Algebraic Surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, vector-bundles, sheaf-cohomology, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be an algebraic surface, $E$ be a rank $r$ vector bundle over $X$, then the Riemann-Roch formula
$$\chi(E)=r\chi(\mathscr O_X)+\frac12\left(c^2_1(E)-c_1(E)c_1(K_X)\right)-c_2(E),$$
holds.

**Q**:
I know how to show it using index theory.

But I do not know how to show it in sheaf language, i.e. by inductive method, construct a sheaf for rank two case.

Could any one help me ?

Comment: For line bundles this can be found in Hartshorne, Algebraic Geometry, V Theorem 1.6 .

Comment: And the general case follows from ibid, Appendix A, Theorem 4.1 (Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch).

Comment: @Niels  For the line bundle case, this is the Riemann-Roch for the embedded curve, and by induction of rank, we need to show the rank $2$ case. And what is ibid?

Comment: For higher rank case just use exact sequence to make the vector bundle to be an extension of two vector bundles of lower ranks, and then use induction

Comment: @DLIN http://lmgtfy.com/?q=ibid